# Having problems displaying structure array content

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to display structure members based on user input, but I don't know if I've stored the input properly.
When I try display all people, it just outputs random numbers.

These are the structures and function prototypes

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15
#define MAX_NUM_PERSON 4
#define MAX_JOB_LENGTH 20

typedef struct birth_date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} person_birth_t;

typedef struct person
{
    char pName[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char job[MAX_JOB_LENGTH];
    person_birth_t  birth_t;    
} person_t[MAX_NUM_PERSON];

void print_menu (void);
void scanPerson(person_t p, int);
void displayPeople(person_t p);
```

This is the main code for the program, a menu is printed asking user to input a number, if a user enters 1 then it prompts them to add a person. Entering 2 displays all people entered.

```
int main(void)
{
    /* TODO */
    print_menu();
    return 0;
}

void print_menu (void)
{
    int choice;
    person_t p;
    static int index = 0;
    int *indexP = NULL;
    indexP = &index;

    /*Print the menu*/

    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
        if (index < MAX_NUM_PERSON){
            scanPerson(p, index);
            ++*indexP;
            print_menu();
        } else {
            printf("Can't add more people - memory full \n");
            print_menu();
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        displayPeople(p);
        break;

        case 3:
        exit(0);
        break;

        default:
        print_menu();
    }
}
 /*function called when add person is chosen from menu */
void scanFlight(person_t p, int index){
    /*printf to enter name*/
    scanf(" %s", p[index].pName);

    /*printf to enter job*/
    scanf("%s", p[index].job);
}

void displayPeople(person_t p){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_PERSON; i++){
        printf("%s %d-%d-%d %s \n",p[i].pName
                                  ,p[i].birth_t.month
                                  ,p[i].birth_t.day
                                  ,p[i].birth_t.year
                                  ,p[i].job);
    }
}
```

I've tried other ways to take input and add it to a struct array, but I'm just not sure how to do it right.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: `scanPerson(p, index);`?? And `++*indexP;` is wrong but likely harmless (you should get a compiler warning)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it seems to compile, that was another problem because I didn't know how to make it check when the maximum amount of people were inputted

Comment: Show the structure declaration.

Comment: If you are using gcc/clang, make sure you include `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow`. If using VS, include `/W3`. For other compilers check what is needed to enable warnings. If we knew what `indexP` was, I could tell you exactly, but without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we are left to guess.

Comment: @Barmar here is the struct declaration: https://pastebin.com/afAMLFNt

Comment: Please, edit the question with the code you linked.

Comment: What is indexP? and index? Please show the entire code or it it difficult to narrow it down.

Comment: You keep calling those snips of code 'functions' but they are not, they are just snippets of code  please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: I've edited the post with the full code

Comment: Don't use recursion for looping, use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
person_t p;
```

Here, you use the local variable `p` (in `print_menu` function), so each recursion, you just print the parameters of the local variable that is not initialized.

To solve it, you can declare `p` as the global variable.

OT, in `scanFlight` function, to avoid overflow, you should change the `scanf` function to:

```
    /*printf to enter name*/
    scanf("%14s", p[index].pName);

    /*printf to enter job*/
    scanf("%20s", p[index].job);
```

And, rename `scanPerson` to `scanFlight`, because i do not see any implementation of `scanPerson` function in your code. I think it's typo, no ?

Comment: `person_t` is an array type, so it's passed as a pointer, not a copy.

Comment: I know, it’s a local array, so each recursion, it’s reseted. When user types number 2 to display people info, the program will show out the values of an uninitialized array.

Comment: It's not a local array. Arrays are passed by reference, they're not copied.

Comment: @Barmar I do not get your idea. I am talking about `person_t p;` that is declared in `print_menu` function, not about the argument of `scanFlight` or `displayPeople` function.

Comment: its ok, I figured it out. I was going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods were working, so instead of trying to figure it out, I scrapped the static index and indexP.
Instead, I initialized p with malloc:

```
person_t *p= malloc(MAX_NUM_PERSON * sizeof(person_t));
```

I changed the scan function to accommodate for the change and made index a pointer instead, and I made the display function pass the index.

When I ran it, the output was correct.